# How can I perform this Recursive Common Table Expression in SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

In this table schema:

```
class Location(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.String(255), primary_key=True)
    parent_id = db.Column(db.String(255), db.ForeignKey('location.id'), nullable=True) 
    type = db.Column(db.String(255))
    name = db.Column(db.String(255))
    options = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=True)
```

I have a parent, suppose this table:

```
> select * from location;
+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+---------+-----------+---------+
| id                                   | parent_id                            | type    | name      | options |
+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+---------+-----------+---------+
| 8821da60-e7d2-11e1-951e-ae16bc2b7368 | 88227a60-e7d2-11e1-951e-ae16bc2b7368 | city    | sengkang  | NULL    |
| 88227a60-e7d2-11e1-951e-ae16bc2b7368 | NULL                                 | country | singapore | NULL    |
+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+---------+-----------+---------+
```

The parent being the **country** object named **singapore**. There can be more nested objects, that are children to **sengkang** just like how **sengkang** is child to **singapore**.

So a single hierachy chain might look like a -> b -> sengkang -> singapore

whereby -> means *is child of*

How can I get all Location objects that have the parent as singapore, including the parent object (singapore)? (in SQLAlchemy please). Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

SA Documentation: [Query.cte](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.cte)

I have to say the new CTE stuff (since 0.76) is pretty good, better than the old way where I had to rework [this](https://bitbucket.org/zzzeek/sqlalchemy/issues/attachments/1859/zzzeek/sqlalchemy/1394229566.78/1859/cte_demo.py).

Anyway, think you're looking for something like this...

```
included_parts = session.query(Location).\
  filter(Location.name=='singapore').\
  cte(name='included_parts', recursive=True)

incl_alias = aliased(included_parts, name="pr")
parts_alias = aliased(Location, name='p')
included_parts = included_parts.union_all(
  session.query(parts_alias).filter(parts_alias.parent_id==incl_alias.c.id)
)

q = session.query(included_parts).all()
```

Comment: can you rewrite your example to answer my question's context? i did read this example but didn't understand what it did without a context. i was hoping to learn CTE through my example, thanks!

Comment: It is/was written for your context, notice how it is querying Location, and Location.name=='singapore' - the variable names are the same as the example because they're just generic names that describe the parts of the query.  Results from the query are:
[(u'88227a60-e7d2-11e1-951e-ae16bc2b7368', None, u'country', u'singapore', None), (u'8821da60-e7d2-11e1-951e-ae16bc2b7368', u'88227a60-e7d2-11e1-951e-ae16bc2b7368', u'city', u'sengkang', None)]

Comment: This works for me without any of the `aliased`s - am I missing something?