# How would I query using sqlalchemy to retrieve all objects from an adjacency list?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

```
class Node(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'node'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    parent_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('node.id'))
    data = Column(String(50))
    children = relationship("Node",
                backref=backref('parent', remote_side=[id])
            )
```

When using this type of model, how could I query for all linked objects of a parent?

In other words, I need a list that contains all the children and children of children, and children of children of children...

Comment: Traversing trees can be done using a recursive CTE: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52408644/how-can-i-write-a-sqlalchemy-query-that-will-return-all-descendants-of-a-node-in, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11994092/how-can-i-perform-this-recursive-common-table-expression-in-sqlalchemy

Answer (score 2):

This is what I ended up doing, probably not the best, but it worked.

```
pks = []

def get_pk(o):
    pks.append(o.pk)
    for a in o.attachments:
        get_pk(a)

get_pk(parent)
```

Answer (score 1):

Query *children* on your node object directly. Check out lazy parameter in sqlalchemy documentation. That will determine, when exactly your list will be queried (with object itself or separately)

See below code for reference

```
parent = Node.query.filter_by(id=1).first()
children_list = n.children
```

P.S.: children_list will have immediate children only. To get grand-children and further, query again and again as needed, check *lazy* parameter for more information